# 3 months of working at a US office of an EU company (EU working contract)

Tags: visa, working-visas, customs

I'm an Italian guy working for a company that has 3 offices outside of Italy.

One of these offices is in the US. Basically, the company is giving me the opportunity to spend some time in one of the international offices (I can choose which one) as an exchange program (the main purpose is to practice English). They will give me an extra budget to be spent for renting a room there and the flight.

The company is not happy about applying for a work visa. I will work under an Italian contract, and I know that it is quite common for some companies to arrange some training in its international offices.

My question is will this be acceptable? Can I apply only for the travel visa (3 months) or will it be rejected?

If this is relevant, I am a statistician with a Master's degree.

Comment: Spending time and training should be OK, actually working (either remotely on your current work or helping the US branch with local projects) probably isn't, which is it? Also, it seems a bit shady for your employer to offer this without a clear understanding of the legal implication and/or providing assistance with the visa.

Comment: The US subsidiary should initiate the process for the issuance of an L-1 visa, most easily [outlined on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-1_visa) as it has all the links, including the required Form I-129 petition.